# Adding a new value into a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I am using Highcharts for visualization and Highcharter generates charts as a nested list similar to the `example_list` below. I'm summarizing it here because the original list is much longer and complex.

```
example_list <- list(
    x = list(
        hc_opts = list(
            series = list(
                list(group = "group_a", data = list(0,2,4,6)),
                list(group = "group_b", data = list(0,3,6,9)),
                list(group = "group_c", data = list(9,4,8,12))))))
```

Just like the group and data nodes, I would like to add an element called `type` at the level of `group` and `data`, but only to the 1st and 3rd elements under `series`. I'm basically looking for an output same as the following:

```
example_list <- list(
    x = list(
        hc_opts = list(
            series = list(
                list(group = "group_a", data = list(0,2,4,6), type = "type_X"),
                list(group = "group_b", data = list(0,3,6,9)),
                list(group = "group_c", data = list(9,4,8,12), type = "type_Y")))))
```

I can do this with a for-loop (because I have vectors for locations and types), but
there should be an elegant way of coding it. My best attempt so far.

```
locations <- c(1,3)
types <- c("type_X","type_Y")
for(i in 1:length(locations)) {
    example_list[["x"]][["hc_opts"]][["series"]][[locations[i]]][["type"]] <- types[i]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as your datasets get more complex, interacting with them also gets more complex. You could use an `lapply` or `mapply`, but I don't think it would provide too much of an advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` :

```
example_list$x$hc_opts$series[c(1, 3)] <- Map(c, 
         example_list$x$hc_opts$series[c(1, 3)], type = types)


#$x
#$x$hc_opts
#$x$hc_opts$series
#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]
#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$group
#[1] "group_a"

#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$data
#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$data[[1]]
#[1] 0

#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$data[[2]]
#[1] 2

#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$data[[3]]
#[1] 4

#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$data[[4]]
#[1] 6


#$x$hc_opts$series[[1]]$type
#[1] "type_X"
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, `Map` works very well and efficiently. I'm not used to working with lists but this reminds me that I should sharpen my skills in lists and `Map`/`mapply`. Many thanks for responding to my first question on slackoverflow ever.